# Como crear desplazamiento al body para que no sea tosco

Tags: html

Como ponerle efecto de desplazamiento al body para que cuando bajemos con el scrollbar el fondo del body; no baje tan tosco sino que halla una pequeña transition agradable.

He realizado una investigación y aquí están ejemplos de lo que necesito :

http://wordpress-custom-scrollbar.softhopper.net/

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Se llama smooth scroll y lo puedes hacer con js o css

Comment: tienes un ejemplo a la mano ?

Comment: para luego eliminar  la pregunta rapido porfa

Comment: oye pero solo funsiona para cuando usas las flechas para subir y bajar pero como hago que se aplique tambien cuando desplace pinche el scrollbar lateral ?

Comment: Como puedo manejar un evento para el Scrollbar y No para el Mouse

Comment: Quiero manipular el Scrollbar usando evento propio de el; el cual no conozco ninguna. Una vez conocido ese evento me gustaria remplazar el evento del Mouse por el de el Scrollbar Smooth para que el efecto se aplique es cuando aya un evento unicamente al Scrollbar Smooth.

Comment: @Gamez cuando realices una pregunta trata de agregar la información que hayas encontrado previa una investigación, en tu pregunta, scripts, imagenes, urls, saludos!

Comment: Esta pregunta esta duplicada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/130893/como-hacer-que-la-pantalla-baje-sin-ser-tosco

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No sé si este es el scrollbar que buscas, es con jquery y espero te sirva.

```js
(function($){
   $(window).load(function(){
    
    $.mCustomScrollbar.defaults.scrollButtons.enable=true; //enable scrolling buttons by default
    $.mCustomScrollbar.defaults.axis="yx"; //enable 2 axis scrollbars by default
    
    $("#content-rds").mCustomScrollbar({theme:"rounded-dots"});
    
    $(".all-themes-switch a").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var $this=$(this),
      rel=$this.attr("rel"),
      el=$(".content");
     switch(rel){
      case "toggle-content":
       el.toggleClass("expanded-content");
       break;
     }
    });
    
   });
  })(jQuery);
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two:700italic,700);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300);

body{
 background-color: #222;
 color: #eee;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-family: "Verdana",Geneva,sans-serif;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 min-width: 480px;
}

h1, h2, h3{
 font-family: "Lobster Two", "Georgia", serif;
 font-weight: 700;
 font-style: italic;
 color: #6bdaea;
}

hr{
 background-color: transparent;
 height: 0;
 border: none;
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.08);
 border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
 margin: 0;
 clear: both;
}

h1{
 margin: 20px 0;
 color: inherit;
}

.content{
 overflow: auto;
 position: relative;
 padding: 20px;
 background: #333;
 margin: 10px;
 width: 740px;
 max-width: 97%;
 height: 400px;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content hr{
 margin-bottom: -10px;
 border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}

.content p{ margin: 30px 0; }

.content p:last-child{ margin-bottom: 5px; }

.content p:nth-child(odd), .content.light p:nth-child(odd){
 background: #444;
 background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
 padding: 5px 10px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px;
}

.content p:nth-child(3n+3){
 color: #bbb;
 background: none;
 padding: 0;
}


.content h2{
 font-size: 200%;
 line-height: 130%;
}

.content h2:first-child{ margin-top: 5px; }

.content:nth-child(odd) h2{
 font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
 font-weight: 300;
 font-style: normal;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1229px){
 .showcase .horizontal-images.content{ width: 1060px; }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1629px){
 .showcase .horizontal-images.content{ width: 700px; }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
 <title>Scrollbar con Jquery</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/h6j1ynikq69ecoz/scroll.css" rel="stylesheet"/> 
</head>

<body> 
    <div id="content-rds" class="content">
    <h2>Scroball con jquery</h2>
    <hr />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p> 
    <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p> 
    <p>Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p> 
    <p>Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur?</p> 
    <p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas...</p>
    <hr />
    <p>Fin del contenido.</p>
    </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/mbxdnhkqpdomxxv/jquery.scrollController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Es el mismo que tiene la página wordpress que pusiste en la pregunta, pero saqué el código de otro lado. Aclaro: no sé quién haya sido el autor original, así que lo coloco sólo a modo de orientación. Si tienes alguna duda puedes comentarme.

Comment: Ya voy a probarlo y te escribo

Comment: Oye ese es; el codigo que busco pero no puedo ejecutarlo en mi computadora, no hace el efecto ni muestra su color  ?

Comment: hace falta meterlo en un servido local ?. Estoy en una pc que no es mia y no tengo las herramientas

Comment: Y de donde lo obtuvistes amigo aver si consigo otras cosas importantes

Comment: Listo amigo solo tenia que aplicar las direcciones del js y css. pero lo probe en 2 navegadores como: Mozilla y Chrome. Pero solo funciona en Mozilla conoces alguna forma de crear comartibilidad con las mismas ?

Comment: Yo estoy usando chrome y me va perfecto. Fíjate si estás colocando estás linkeando estos dos archivos: scroll.css (este es el que modifica la apariencia del scrollbar) y  jquery.scrollController.js (este es el que le coloca el diseño al div que tengas de contenedor).

Comment: ok ya reviso el codigo

Comment: yo ya tengo esto :  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scrollbarr.js">
 porque se lo asigne. Esta mal ?. Y este :  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="scrollbar.css">

Comment: Asigne los css y js en un archivo con un nombre que le asigne sera este el error  que tengo ?

Comment: Así no se linkea el archivo javascript, es con <script src="nombre.js"></script>

Comment: Si ya me acabo de dar cuenta :-) es el producto del estres pero finooooo graciasss. vere si se lo puedo aplicar al body

Comment: Oye disculpa de que fuente lo conseguistes porque estuve buscando y no escontre nada ni la forma de encontralo

Comment: Revisé el código fuente de una página parecida a la que tú mandaste y pues copié las funciones que modificaban la barra :P

Comment: voy hacer otra pregunta de como ponercelo al body ya que quiero salir de este pedasito de codigo para hacer otras cosas que que estoy contra el tiempo de mi propia meta de tiempo. es mi primera web y voy con todo y detalles ya que no me gusta nada que este mal presentado y pobre en contenido

Comment: Yo pense en tomar los codigos del code y buscarlo uno a uno hasta encontrar la pista que me diera al problema :-), bueno haré la pregunta nueva para ver como aplicárselo al body. gracias por tu ayuda y al resto aunque no dieran con el problema son de igualmente honrados SALUDOS

Comment: Ya hice mi nueva pregunta me ayudas ?, aqui el link : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/130956/como-quito-el-scrollbar-al-body

Comment: Ofertare 50 mas que dices; dime y lo pongo apenas lo tenga para que seas el primero ??; en 20 minutos hago la oferta espero tu respuesta antes @Andy Samuel Alvarado

Answer (score 3):

Si entendí bien lo que deseas lograr...

Se puede hacer con algunos trucos de `CSS`, por ejemplo puedes poner todo dentro de un container en el cual irá todo el contenido con el "smooth scrool", y jugar con la [`perspectiva`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/perspective) y las [`transformaciones`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/transform) para poder alejar en el plano Z con `translateZ()` y a la vez acercar utilizando `scale()` el contenido y que exista la ilusión de un scroll no tan tosco, algo así:

El CSS

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.smooth-container {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-perspective: 300px;
  perspective: 300px;
}

.smooth-container__group {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.smooth-container__layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.smooth-container__layer--deep {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-1500px) scale(6);
  transform: translateZ(-1500px) scale(6);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

El HTML

```
<div class="smooth-container">
  <div class="smooth-container__group">
    <div class="smooth-container__layer smooth-container__layer--deep">
      Tu contenido
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

La ventaja de esto es que todo se puede lograr con `CSS`, aparte de ser 100% responsivo.

Lo probé en macOS con Firefox, Chrome y Safari. Te dejo el [link a codepen](https://codepen.io/kacospro/pen/BJORZY) por si lo quieres ver mas claro.

Espero haber sido de ayuda

Comment: Creo que esto no es lo que busca, ya que sigue moviéndose brusco.

Comment: Pienso lo mismo, ademas lo veo igual solo que tiene un scroll demás.

Comment: Tienes razón @JorgeLuis el scroll demás lo causaba el `min-height`, te dejo el [codepen](https://codepen.io/kacospro/pen/BJORZY) para que veas un ejemplo funcional, siempre puedes jugar con el `translateZ` y su `scale` para que te des cuenta de como disminuye la velocidad del scroll tanto en los clicks a la scrollbar como con la rueda del mouse. Cualquier recomendación para mejorarlo es bienvenida ;)

Comment: Cierto @kacospro busco es desminuir la velocidad del scroll tanto por Clicks al ScrollBar como con la rueda del mouse esto Busco