# ¿Como quito el scrollbar al body?

Tags: html, jquery, css, scroll

Busco como quitarle el `scrollbar` al `body` para asignarle este otro `scrollbar` que pueden visualizar si lo ejecutan pero esta debe incluir las mismas funciones de desplazamiento

```js
(function($) {
  $(window).load(function() {

    $.mCustomScrollbar.defaults.scrollButtons.enable = true; //enable scrolling buttons by default
    $.mCustomScrollbar.defaults.axis = "yx"; //enable 2 axis scrollbars by default

    $("#content-rds").mCustomScrollbar({
      theme: "rounded-dots"
    });

    $(".all-themes-switch a").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var $this = $(this),
        rel = $this.attr("rel"),
        el = $(".content");
      switch (rel) {
        case "toggle-content":
          el.toggleClass("expanded-content");
          break;
      }
    });

  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two:700italic,700);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300);
body {
  background-color: #222;
  color: #eee;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Verdana", Geneva, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 480px;
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  font-family: "Lobster Two", "Georgia", serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #6bdaea;
}

hr {
  background-color: transparent;
  height: 0;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08);
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  margin: 0;
  clear: both;
}

h1 {
  margin: 20px 0;
  color: inherit;
}

.content {
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #333;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 740px;
  max-width: 97%;
  height: 400px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content hr {
  margin-bottom: -10px;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}

.content p {
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.content p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.content p:nth-child(odd),
.content.light p:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #444;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  padding: 5px 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.content p:nth-child(3n+3) {
  color: #bbb;
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.content h2 {
  font-size: 200%;
  line-height: 130%;
}

.content h2:first-child {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.content:nth-child(odd) h2 {
  font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1229px) {
  .showcase .horizontal-images.content {
    width: 1060px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1629px) {
  .showcase .horizontal-images.content {
    width: 700px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <title>Scrollbar con Jquery</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/h6j1ynikq69ecoz/scroll.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>

<body>
  <div id="content-rds" class="content">
    <h2>Scroball con jquery 1</h2>
    <hr />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    <p>Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
    <p>Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem
      ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur?</p>
    <p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas...</p>
    <hr />

    <h2>Scroball con jquery 2</h2>
    <hr />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    <p>Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
    <p>Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem
      ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur?</p>
    <p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas...</p>
    <hr />

    <h2>Scroball con jquery 3</h2>
    <hr />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    <p>Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
    <p>Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem
      ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur?</p>
    <p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas...</p>
    <hr />

    <h2>Scroball con jquery 4</h2>
    <hr />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    <p>Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p>
    <p>Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem
      ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur?</p>
    <p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas...</p>
    <hr />
    <p>Fin del contenido.</p>
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/mbxdnhkqpdomxxv/jquery.scrollController.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: especifica mas tu pregunta

Comment: @x-rw Ya modifique el codigo ejecutalo para que lo observes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Primero debes esconder el scroll que trae por defecto el navegador, así que en style.css agregarás esto al inicio:

```
*{
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Y en el script, donde está esto

```
$("#content-rds").mCustomScrollbar({theme:"rounded-dots"});
```

lo cambiarás por `$("body").mCustomScrollbar({theme:"rounded-dots"});`

```js
(function($){
   $(window).load(function(){
    
    $.mCustomScrollbar.defaults.scrollButtons.enable=true; //enable scrolling buttons by default
    $.mCustomScrollbar.defaults.axis="yx"; //enable 2 axis scrollbars by default
    
    $("body").mCustomScrollbar({theme:"rounded-dots"});
    
    $(".all-themes-switch a").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     var $this=$(this),
      rel=$this.attr("rel"),
      el=$(".content");
     switch(rel){
      case "toggle-content":
       el.toggleClass("expanded-content");
       break;
     }
    });
    
   });
  })(jQuery);
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster+Two:700italic,700);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:300);

*{
   height: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
  }
  
body{
 background-color: #222;
 color: #eee;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-family: "Verdana",Geneva,sans-serif;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 min-width: 480px;
}

h1, h2, h3{
 font-family: "Lobster Two", "Georgia", serif;
 font-weight: 700;
 font-style: italic;
 color: #6bdaea;
}

hr{
 background-color: transparent;
 height: 0;
 border: none;
 border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.08);
 border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
 margin: 0;
 clear: both;
}

h1{
 margin: 20px 0;
 color: inherit;
}

.content{
 overflow: auto;
 position: relative;
 padding: 20px;
 background: #333;
 margin: 10px;
 width: 740px;
 max-width: 97%;
 height: 400px;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
}

.content hr{
 margin-bottom: -10px;
 border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}

.content p{ margin: 30px 0; }

.content p:last-child{ margin-bottom: 5px; }

.content p:nth-child(odd), .content.light p:nth-child(odd){
 background: #444;
 background: rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
 padding: 5px 10px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 3px; -moz-border-radius: 3px; border-radius: 3px;
}

.content p:nth-child(3n+3){
 color: #bbb;
 background: none;
 padding: 0;
}


.content h2{
 font-size: 200%;
 line-height: 130%;
}

.content h2:first-child{ margin-top: 5px; }

.content:nth-child(odd) h2{
 font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
 font-weight: 300;
 font-style: normal;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1229px){
 .showcase .horizontal-images.content{ width: 1060px; }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1629px){
 .showcase .horizontal-images.content{ width: 700px; }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
 <title>Scrollbar con Jquery</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
 <link href="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/h6j1ynikq69ecoz/scroll.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

</head>

<body> 
    <h2>Scroball con jquery afectando el body</h2>
    <hr />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p> 
    <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p> 
    <p>Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p> 
    <p>Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur?</p> 
    <p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas...</p>
    <hr />

    <h2>Scroball con jquery 2</h2>
    <hr />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p> 
    <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p> 
    <p>Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p> 
    <p>Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur?</p> 
    <p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas...</p>
    <hr />

    <h2>Scroball con jquery 3</h2>
    <hr />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p> 
    <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p> 
    <p>Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p> 
    <p>Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur?</p> 
    <p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas...</p>
    <hr />

    <h2>Scroball con jquery 4</h2>
    <hr />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p> 
    <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p> 
    <p>Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt.</p> 
    <p>Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur?</p> 
    <p>Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas...</p>
    <hr />
    <p>Fin del contenido.</p>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/mbxdnhkqpdomxxv/jquery.scrollController.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

De nuevo, si tienes dudas, deja tu comentario.

Comment: Perfecto amigo graciassss

Comment: No me parece buena idea usar `* {...}`, cuando lo que se busca es afectar solo al documento. En su lugar yo usaria `html, body {...}`, acotando el efecto de la regla.

Comment: gracias por tu opinion es buena , porfa si pueden ayudarme a generar puntos por estas preguntas estaria encantado ya que probablemente estaria haciendo recompensa en futuras preguntas.

Comment: Me ayudan @Andy Samuel Alvarado y el resto que lo vean porfa

Comment: Me ayudan @Marcos y el resto que lo vean porfa

Answer (score 1):

usa esto:

```
body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```